# C, IRC BOT. warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char*

Tags: c, compiler-errors, char

I'm trying to code an IRC bot. The bot connects to the server, however I can't get it to join a channel.

```
int conn;
char sbuf[512];

// Function I'm trying to use
void join(char *fmt, ...){
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vsnprintf(sbuf,512, fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    printf("<< %s",sbuf);
    write(conn,sbuf,strlen(sbuff));
}

// in main function 
int main(){
    const char * chanm = "test";

    // Here is where I get my error, line 38
    join("JOIN %s\r\n", chanm);
}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I get the error message:
ircbot.c:38 warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function heading to:

```
void join(const char *fmt, ...){
```

The problem is that `"JOIN %s\r\n"` is a *constant* string, and you were trying to pass it to a non-constant `char *`. Since you don't intend to modify `fmt` within your `join` function, you should declare it as `const char *fmt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with:

```
void join(const char *fmt, ...)
//        ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, a string literal has a non-const type, even though it is undefined behaviour to attempt to modify the contents of a string literal. For example, this is **not allowed** in C, even though a compiler is allowed to compile it without emitting a warning or error:

```
    char *str = "Hello World!";
    str[4] = 'x'; // undefined behaviour
```

In the above, the string literal `"Hello World!"` has the type `char[13]`. To prevent accidental modification of string literals, some compilers treat string literals as `const char[]` types instead. The most it can do is issue a diagnostic/warning because technically speaking it is still valid C. There are two ways around your problem:

1. If a function needs to modify a string, it must be `char *` type, so this means you need to pass it a modifiable string, not a string literal. This can be achieved by creating an array:

   char buf[1000] = "String literal";
   function(buf, sizeof buf, ...);
2. If the function doesn't need to modify the string (such as in your case), you can [and should] have your function only accept `const char *`. This way, both modifiable and unmodifiable strings can be passed to your function without issues.

   ```
   function(const char *arg, ...);

   // somewhere else:

   function("Acceptable", 1, 2, 3);

   char buf[20] = "Also acceptable!";
   function(buf, 1, 2, 3);
   ```